# Got questions? VS Have questions?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, conversational-deletion

My purpose is to ask if the reader of the phrase has any questions regarding the topic. Are both of these sentences correct? To me, it feels like "Got questions?" is more active - as if it implies that some questions may have popped into your head; if yes - let us know.

Got questions?
Have questions?

Note with more details about the context:
If the reader has any questions, they should contact the support team. The language should be informal. For example: "Got questions about maths/services? Let us know and we'll help you out."

Comment: It is common to say or be asked "Any questions?" or "Do you have any questions?" Using **got** doesn't work at all for me: only in the context of asking a speaker "Did you get any questions?" So if I **got** a question, it would be asked *of* me not *by* me.

Comment: What if I want to ask if the person has questions about a particular subject?
Questions about instructions/school subject? Does it influence the decision which version it is better to use?

Comment: The snappy (and idiomatic) way to ask is "Any questions?" not "Got questions?" or "Have questions?"

Comment: "Any questions about maths?" Is it appropriate?

Comment: I think "got" used like this is more common in the US than in the UK.  Thus I conclude that @WeatherVane is not in the US.

Comment: I think you need some more context. The post implies "Got questions?" is *written* somewhere. So are you writing something in informal style? How should the reader respond?

Comment: Okay, I will add more context. 
If the reader has any questions, they should contact the support team. The language should be informal. For example: "Got questions about maths/services? Let us know and we'll help you out."

Comment: "Got questions?" is short for "Have you got any questions?"  It's informal, but perfectly idiomatic in the US.  "Have questions?" is a bit less idiomatic, and is mostly used in a context such as "Have questions?  Call 1-800-SUPIDITY for further information."

Comment: It recalls, in the US, a commercial of a few years ago, “Got milk?”

Comment: Got milk?  It’s not a current cultural reference, but the “Got X?” type of question was used for a while in a variety of quirky ways.